# deleting combinations of vector from a vector of vectors

Tags: c++, vector

I'm working on the 4 sum problem in Leetcode. I'm trying to do it using hash table. I'm stuck at removing combinations of a given vector in a vector of vectors. For example I have a vector of vectors

```
v = [[1,4,0,5],[1,5,0,4],[4,5,0,1],[2,3,0,5],[2,5,0,3],[3,5,0,2],[2,4,1,3],[3,4,1,2]]
```

I want  to remove the combinations of [1,4,0,5], [2,3,0,5] and [2,4,1,3] so that in my final vector of vectors, the combinations of vectors should not be present. It should be like

```
v_final = [[1,4,0,5,],[2,3,0,5],[2,4,1,3]]
```

I'm completely clueless regarding how to do it. Can someone please help me getting `v_final` from `v`?

Comment: What do you mean by combination? You've removed [1,5,0,4] and [4,5,0,1] for example. Why were these "combinations" to be removed?

Comment: Do you need hash based solution -  with additional memory, or equals based solution - without additional memory ?

Comment: By "combinations" did you mean "permutations"?

Comment: Do you mean you want to remove duplicates, leaving only unique elements, where permutations are considered duplicates?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure if I understood the question correctly. Suppose you have

```
v = { { 1,0} , {0,1} , {1,2}}
```

and the final vector should only have

```
v_final = { {1,0}, {1,2}}
```

because you consider `{1,0}` and `{0,1}` as the same element (those are permutations not "combinations"). Further I suppose that each number appears only once in the inner vectors.

If that is the case, you choose the wrong data structure. Your inner element should be `std::unordered_set`s. A set can contain each element only once.

If you also use a `std::unordered_set` for the outer container, your transformation becomes unnecessary, because after this:

```
 std::unordered_set<std::unordered_set<int>> x;
 x.insert( { 1,2} );
 x.insert( { 2,1} );
```

`x` will contain only a single element.

If you need the vector of vectors for other reasons, I would still use the `unordered_set` and simply fill the set from the vector.

Comment: What if each number may appear more than once in the inner vectors? Can you please add this to the answer? Would this do - std::unordered_set<std::vector<int>> ?

Answer (score 2):

*As a complement of the already given answer...*

If you want to do it "manually", without using `std::unordered_set`, you could use [`std::is_permutation`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/is_permutation/) to detect the permutations.

This may look as follows:

```
std::vector <std::vector<int>> v {{1, 2, 3}, {1, 3, 2}, {1, 2, 4}, {4, 2, 1}, {3, 4, 5}};

for(long long i = static_cast<long long>(v.size())-1; i >= 0; --i)
{
    for(std::size_t j = 0; j < static_cast<std::size_t>(i); ++j)
    {
        if(std::is_permutation(v[static_cast<std::size_t>(i)].begin(), v[static_cast<std::size_t>(i)].end(), v[j].begin(), v[j].end()))
        {
            v.erase(v.begin()+i);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

If you print `v` after these loops, every duplicate/permutation will be removed.

I did the test, the output I got is (as expected):

> 1, 2, 3
>   1, 2, 4
>   3, 4, 5

---

**EDIT:** Note that `std::is_permutation` assumes that the second range to compare does contain at least as many elements as the first range to compare.

Therefore if `v` can contain vectors of different sizes, you should check for size equality before calling `std::is_permutation` (because if the sizes does not match, the inner vectors to compare can't be the same).